# Check a style of a class html via VBA Webdriver

Tags: vba, selenium, class, webdriver

Using VBA, webdriver, Chrome as navigator, I would like to check the style of a class in html page.
This is the class :
`<div class="ice-sub-mon-mid idle" style="display: block;"><span class="ice-sub-mon-img"></span></div>`

here is the full xpath :
`/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]`

To be clear, I would like to check if the style is `display: block;` or not that text.

I can find the class like this :
`.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]")`

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please note that SO is not meant as a 'can you please provide this code for me' repository. It is intended as a helpful resource for those that run into problems whilst working out their particular challenge? Perhaps have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

It helps if you describe what you have tried, what code have you used, what errors occur and at what stage in the process. In short; elaborate on the state of your code and problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the syntax to get the value of the attribute:
`.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]").getAttribute("whichever-attribute-you-need")`

You will then need to compare it with the value you expect.

May I suggest you to use relative xPaths? It will be more maintainable :)

Have a good day